# Bound On Matrix Norm wrt Eigenvalues Of Matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

The norm of a matrix is defined as 
\begin{equation}
                      ||A|| = \mbox{max}_{<u|u>=1} |\langle u|A|u\rangle|,
\end{equation}

and I want to find out the lower bound on this norm in terms of the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of the matrix A defined over a complex field. For a Hermitian matrix, this is easy as the vector $|u>$ can be expressed in terms of the eigenvectors of the Hermitian matrix(which span the space). 
 However, for a general matrix A, I have little clue where to begin.

Comment: I suppose this is the [bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation) of quantum mechanics. My question is how do you know that $\langle u|A|u\rangle$ is real ? This is obviously necessary to take the max. Doesn't this imply that $A$ is hermitian ?

Comment: I think you mean that
$$
||A|| = \max_{\langle u|u\rangle =1} |\langle u|A|u\rangle |
$$
This $\|A\|$ is commonly known as the [numerical radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range) of $A$.

Comment: [This paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379582901550) may be of interest. The first few properties look like what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks, yes I meant the absolute value of the matrix element (made the edit).

Comment: Thanks, the answer was in the paper.